# "Data source is an invalid type" exception when binding a single row to a listview

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have grid view to show all customers names, and when a user click on any name, I use a listview to show that information of the selected customer.

So, in the past, if I have more than one customer in the page, I will have a grid view fill, and the listview is empty until the user selects any customer.

this is the code:

```
var results = MyClass.GetCustomerInformation(CallerId);
rowCount = results.Rows.Count;
CallerId = rowCount > 0 ? results.Rows[0][4].ToString() : CallerId;
if (rowCount > 1)
{
    ListView1.Enabled = false;
    GridView1.DataSource = results;
    GridView1.DataBind();
}
else
{
    GridView1.Enabled = false;
    ListView1.DataSource = results;
    ListView1.DataBind();
}
```

#### Now

I need the listview to have the first customer when there are more than one customer.

So, I edited my code to this code:

```
var results = MyClass.GetCustomerInformation(CallerId);
rowCount = results.Rows.Count;
CallerId = rowCount > 0 ? results.Rows[0][4].ToString() : CallerId;
if (rowCount > 1)
{
    //new
    ListView1.DataSource = results.Rows[0];
    ListView1.DataBind();
    //new
    GridView1.DataSource = results;
    GridView1.DataBind();
}
else
{
    GridView1.Enabled = false;
    ListView1.DataSource = results;
    ListView1.DataBind();
}
```

But I got this exception:

> Data source is an invalid type.  It must be either an `IListSource`, `IEnumerable`, or `IDataSource`.

#### Note

The function `GetCustomerInformation` returns `DataTable` type

Comment: What part of that message do you not understand? What is the type of the data source? Does that type implement either `IListSource`, `IEnumerable`, or `IDataSource`?

Comment: @JohnSaunders I understand the message, but I don't know why it shows, I used the same code, which I was using in the past, and which is working perfectly, so why now when I took the first row, I got that exception

Comment: Because one row is not the same as a collection of rows!

Comment: @JohnSaunders I edited the question, and added the type of the returned function.

Comment: The `DataRow` type does not implement `IListSource`, `IEnumerable`, or `IDataSource`.

Comment: @JohnSaunders now I got you,  I have to cast it to datatable, right?

Answer (score 1):

When you set the data source to a single row, you caused your problem.

The `DataRow` type does not implement `IListSource`, `IEnumerable`, or `IDataSource`. You need to pass one of those to the `DataSource` property, but you passed `DataRow` instead.

The thing to do is to create an `IEnumerable<DataRow>` from your single `DataRow`. Try this:

```
ListView1.DataSource = new DataRow[]{results.Rows[0]};
```

This creates an array of `DataRow` which contains only your first row. `DataRow[]` implements `IEnumerable<DataRow>`, so it works.

Comment: +1: thanks. its a better idea that escaped my thought.

Comment: I got this exception `DataBinding: 'System.Data.DataRow' does not contain a property with the name 'MembershipID'.` although my query from the database contains membershipid

Comment: Use the debugger to see if this one particular row has that column. Or, before setting the DataSource, add this line: `var membershipID = results.Rows[0]["MembershipID"];` see if the new line gets the exception.